What is the meaning of weak topology?
In GTM96, A Course in Functional Analysis, the weak topology is as follows:
Definition: If $X$ is LCS, the weak topology on $X$, denoted by "wk" or $\sigma(X, X^*)$, is the topology defined by the family of seminorms $\{p_{x^*}: x^* \in X^*\}$, where $p_{x^*}(x) = x^*(x)$.
My question is how to define the weak topology by the family of seminorms? The family of seminorms is as a base or subbase? I think, if it is topology base, then the weak topology mayby any union of these seminorms, but if it is subbase, then the weak topology is any union of finite intersection of seminorms. My idea is right?

Your idea is right. It is very general idea of any topological space. But with this idea, attacking the problems of topological vector spaces, precisely normed spaces, is difficult.

Yes, functional analysis is so difficult for me. It is easy to understand the concepts, but presicely proof and exercise maybe not clear. So, the above question, the family of seminorms is as a base? namely the weak topology is generated by any union of these seminorms? Thanks very much.

One quibble: the elements of $X^$ are not quite seminorms... we need to take absolute values: what you want instead is seminorms $x\to |x^(x)|$.

Yes, sure. It is a typo.

The elements of the family $\{p_{x^*} : x^* \in X^*\}$ are not subsets of $X$, so it makes no sense to assert that this family is a base or sub-base on $X$ --- each individual element of a base or sub-base on $X$ must be a subset of $X$.
Instead, each element of that family is a function $p_{x^*} : X \to \mathbb R$. Using those functions we can then write down a collection $\mathcal B$ of subsets of $X$ that ought to be open subsets of $X$, if one knew that each of the functions $p_{x^*}$ is continuous. Namely:
$$\mathcal B = \{(p_{x^*})^{-1}(a,b) \mid x^* \in X^*, a,b \in \mathbb R, a < b \}
$$
The weak topology on $X$ is the topology having $\mathcal B$ as a sub-base, i.e. all unions of finite intersections of elements of the set $\mathcal B$. It may be described as the weakest topology on $X$ such that each function $p_{x^*} : X \to \mathbb R$ is continuous, which means precisely this: letting $\{\mathcal T_i\}_{i \in I}$ be the (indexed) set of all topologies $\mathcal T_i$ on $X$ having the property that each function $p_{x^*}$ is continuous with respect to $\mathcal T_i$, the weak topology on $X$ is $\bigcap_{i \in I} \mathcal T_i$.
